# Как вытянуть данные из другой таблицы по ID?

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Учусь делать Api для своего сайта, и не могу понять как вытянуть данные из другой таблицы!

**models.js**

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product',{
    id:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true, autoIncrement:true},
    catalog_number:{type: DataTypes.STRING},
    title:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    old_price:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER,defaultValue: 0},
    price:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
    image:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    image_class:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, defaultValue: 'img'},
    is_desc_noindex:{type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false},
    desc_text:{type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false},
    short_text:{type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false},
})

const Order = sequelize.define('order',{
    id:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true, autoIncrement:true},
    fio:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    phone:{type: DataTypes.DECIMAL, allowNull: false, unique: true},
    email:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique:true, validate: {isEmail: true}},
    adress:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    products_id:{type: DataTypes.STRING}
})

Order.hasMany(Product, {as: "order_prod"})
Product.belongsTo(Order)
```

**orderController.js**

```
  async getAll(req, res){
        let order = await Order.findAll({
            include: [{model: Product, as: 'order_prod'}],
            where: { id:[1]}
        })
        return res.json(order)
    }
```

Я хотел сделать что бы в базу передавалось значение id товаров (придумал только через STRING, не знаю как с фронта передать массивом), а потом при необходимости (возможно в админке) выводить это в соответствующие поля.

Answer (score 0):

В Sequelize есть различные операторы. В частности вам нужен Op.in
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators
Получим

```
where: {
 id: {
  [Op.in]: [нужный массив]
 }
}
.
```

Comment: Там где нужный массив для теста ставил цифру 1, но возвращаться пустой массив. Хотя в таблице есть несколько товаров и 1 заказ.